# Dynamically load specific User Control from dropdownlist in autopostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, autopostback

I have an asp.net webpage with a Dropdown control like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="TypeDrp" runat="server" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="LoadCorrectForm" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem>X</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Y</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Z</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <br />

    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I want to dynamically load a control in placeholder1 after postback. which are in folder named "myControls" like this:

```
XTypeForm.ascx
YTypeForm.ascx
ZTypeForm.ascx
```

how should I call and use them correctly?
some one told me to use sth like this:

```
protected void LoadCorrectForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SelectedValue = TypeDrp.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Control userControl = GetSpecificUserControl(SelectedValue);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();   // Remove old user control
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(userControl);
}
```

but It has errors and I do not know how to change it for my own code?

Comment: the problem is in TypeDrp.SelectedItem.ToString()

Comment: Item is a collection of text and value. Where are you putting the value "Name of the control to be loaded". If it is in value of the dropdown then replace it by selected value.

Answer (score 0):

To load an ascx user control, use some code like this:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) 
{ 
   WebUserControl1 uc = 
   (WebUserControl1) Page.LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx"); 
   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="TypeDrp" runat="server" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="LoadCorrectForm" AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:ListItem Value="XTypeForm.ascx">X</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="YTypeForm.ascx">Y</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="ZTypeForm.ascx" >Z</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then use

> string SelectedValue = TypeDrp.SelectedValue.ToString();

it will work.

Comment: my control files are in another folder named:"myControls".  in addition PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(....) does not accept string data type. but how should I call control?

Comment: string SelectedValue = "foldername/"+TypeDrp.SelectedValue.ToString();

Comment: or even string SelectedValue = "~/"+TypeDrp.SelectedValue.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will work but you can try like this

```
string SelectedValue = "foldername/"+TypeDrp.SelectedValue.ToString();
var lobjucModelTabs = (SelectedValue)LoadControl("~/yourfolder/"+SelectedValue);
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lobjucModelTabs );
```

If it does not work
then you will have to use switch statement lke this.

```
 string filename = TypeDrp.SelectedValue;
        UserControl userControl;
        switch (filename)
        {
            case "XTypeForm.ascx":
                UserControl ctrl = (XTypeForm)LoadControl("NewFolder1/XTypeForm.ascx");
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
                break;
        }
```